# PHP Curl vs Python Requests

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests

I am currently writing a piece of code to interface with an API in Python. Supplied by the company that hosts the API is a PHP script that logs into the API given the correct username and password, retrieved the current event ID (JSON format), and then logs out. This works perfectly.

Currently, I am in the process of writing a script in Python to do the very same thing, the current code is shown below. It logs in and out successfully, however, when it tries to retrieve the current event ID I get the status code 404, suggesting that the URL doesn't exist, despite this same URL working with the PHP code.

PHP Code:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'https://website.api.com/');
define('API_USER', 'username');
define('API_PASS', 'password');

$cookiefile = tempnam(__DIR__, "cookies");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);

$loginParams = array(
  'username' => API_USER,
  'password' => API_PASS
);
$obj = CurlPost($ch, BASE_URL . '/api/login', $loginParams);
  if( $obj->success )
{
  echo 'API login successful.' . PHP_EOL;
}

$obj = CurlGet($ch, BASE_URL . '/api/current-event-id');
echo 'API current event ID: ' . $obj->currentEventId . PHP_EOL;

// logout of the API
$obj = CurlGet($ch, BASE_URL . '/api/logout' );
if( $obj->success )
{
  echo 'Logged out successfully.' . PHP_EOL;
}

curl_close($ch);

exit(0);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Functions
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Run cURL post and decode the returned JSON object.
function CurlPost($ch, $url, $params)
{
  $query = http_build_query($params);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($query));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);    

  $output=curl_exec($ch);

  $obj = json_decode($output);

  return $obj;
}

// Run cURL get and decode the returned JSON object.
function CurlGet($ch, $url)
{
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');

  $output=curl_exec($ch);
  $obj = json_decode($output);
  return $obj;
}
```

Python Code:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://website.api.com/';
API_USER = "username";
API_PASS = "password";
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

PARAMS = {'username':API_USER,'password':API_PASS}
session = requests.Session()

# Login
resp = session.post(BASE_URL + '/api/login',data=PARAMS)
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print("*** ERROR ***: Login failed.")
else:
    print("API login successful.")

resp = session.get(BASE_URL + '/api/current-event-id', headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.text)
# Logout
resp = session.get(BASE_URL + '/api/logout')
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print("*** ERROR ***: Logout failed.")
else:
    print("API logout successful.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my API will only accept cookies transferred in the header, so I wrote a slight hack that dumped the cookiejar into a string that could be sent in the header file.

```
cookies = json.dumps(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(resp.cookies));
cookies = cookies.replace('"', '')
cookies = cookies.replace('{', '')
cookies = cookies.replace('}', '')
cookies = cookies.replace(': ', '=')
cookies = cookies.replace(',', ';')

headers = {'Cookie':cookies}
resp = session.get(BASE_URL + '/api/current-event-id', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ideal to change BASE_URL to:

```
'https://website.api.com'
```

the code looks fine to me when compared to php and should normally work.(Shouldn't you be passing some kind of authentication like a token?).

try debugging your API using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into postman. As for authentication, this is handled by a session cookie that is created at login. In the PHP code, this is handled by "CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR" from what I understand in Python "requests.Session()" should do a similar thing.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.